# image cropper in ng dialog scope value is not updating in controller (Angular.JS)

Tags: angularjs, controller, angularjs-scope, crop, ng-dialog

I am facing a issue, can any one help me out?

angular image cropper in ng dialog, scope value is not updating in controller.

Please help me out.

Thanks in advance.